# GPS emulators on Linux/Windows

Tags: gps, software-recommendations

I'd like to know if there are any GPS emulators available?

What I'd like to do is the following: Given a series of straight lines and a vehicle moving at a certain velocity on the lines, I'd like the GPS emulator to write data about the vehicle's position to a computer port or somewhere in /dev/.

I'd like to  query this port using Python and read information. I googled but I'm not sure what to make of the information available. GPSFake is one of the results. Can it do what I'm asking?

Comment: like http://www.nmeasoft.com/product/gpssimulator/?ckattempt=1 ?

Comment: Thanks. I'll check that out.

Comment: The installer seems to be in Korean. I don't want to install something I don't understand.

Comment: I have looked a bit online and found the following interesting options:
- NMEA simulator: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nmea-simulator/dfhcgoinjchfcfnnkecjpjcnknlipcll?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon
- NMEA generator: https://www.nmeagen.org/
I have not tried any of the above myself. Hope it helps.

Comment: Both are interesting. Thanks.

Comment: For software recommendations there is the [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange.